# How to sort standard input strings alphabetically in C++?

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream> 
using namespace std;

int main (int argc, char **argv)
{
    int i = 0, j = 0;
    string temp;

    for (i = 1; i < argc; ++i)
    {
         for (j = i+1; j < argc; ++j)
         {
              if (argv[i] > argv[j])
              {
                   temp = argv[i];
                   argv[i] = argv[j];
                   argv[j] = temp;
              }
          }
     }
}
```

I don't know why but i am getting this Error when i compile it.

> trial2.cpp:109:14: error: assigning to 'char *' from incompatible type 'string' (aka'basic_string, allocator >')
>                             argv[j] = temp;
>                                     ^ ~~~~
>   //temp is my temporary string.

Comment: it's not possible to do this in-place (without violating the c++ standard), you'd need to make your own vector of pointers and sort that

Comment: @PcAF...Error is not because of string header. It is because `string` cannot be implicitly casted to `char*`. We have to make use of `string::c_str()` function.

Comment: Also, is there a specific reason to do a bubble sort like this instead of just calling 'sort' on a list of strings? Like here: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/list/list/sort/

Comment: @sgarizvi Oh, I read word `incompatible` as `incomplete`, I'll delete my comment.

Comment: Change your `string temp;` to `char* temp;`, and it just might work with your particular compiler/toolchain/OS. Then learn the difference between C style string and `std::string`.

Comment: @M.M At least on unixy environments, modifying `argv` is perfectly fine and a lot of libraries use it (you pass them `argv`, they remove the options they understand, leaving rest for you to handle in your appliation code). Therefore I doubt it violates the standard.

Comment: @hyde in fact the C++ standard appears to be completely silent on this issue. Since it does not define that that `argv[n]` is modifiable, it could be argued that modifying it is undefined behaviour (by omission).  (The C standard differs and does appear to say that the argv pointers are non-modifiable)

Comment: @M.M In practice at least POSIX-like environments do define that `argv` is modifiable, in them it is perfectly safe thing to do (within some constraints, but at least removing items and changing order of them is ok), and any compiler conforming to the platform's requirements supports it. Not sure of Windows, but it's probably similarly ok there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two errors in the code:

1. As @hyde pointed out, `temp` should be `char*` and not `string`
2. `argv[i] > argv[j]` looks like pointer comparison i.e. it will compare the value of the address rather than comparing the string. I suggest using `strcmp` methods for comparing two `char*` (then you need to `#include <string>` to use this method)

Suggested code (not sure if totally bug free or not, but hopefully it's the case):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main (int argc, char **argv)
{
    int i = 0, j = 0;
    char* temp;

    for (i = 1; i < argc; ++i)
    {
         for (j = i+1; j < argc; ++j)
         {
              if (strcmp(argv[i] , argv[j]) > 0)
              {
                   temp = argv[i];
                   argv[i] = argv[j];
                   argv[j] = temp;
              }
          }
     }
    for(i = 0; i < argc; i++){
        cout << argv[i]<< endl;
    }
}
```

Note the final for loop is to check if the output is sorted. I tried your comparison `argv[i] > argv[j]` rather than `strcmp` and it does not seem to work on my machine.

Comment: Of course it has to be noted, that a lot better and more "C++" solution would be to first copy C strings from `argv` to `std::vector< std::string >`, and then sort that.

Comment: uhhh that's actually true. thanks for the tips :P @hyde

Comment: Thank you guys i use string vector to store all argv and then sorted them out.

Answer (score 1):

Error spring up becouse it fails cast type `string` to `char *`. But it must work reversed (therefore your `temp = argv[i];` does't fails).
Don't write to `argv`(you can, but I do not recommend).
Simple way: Copy `argv` to to some array of `string` before sorting:
`

```
string *argv_strings = new string[argc - 1];
for(int i = 0; i < argc - 1; ++i)
{
    argv_strings[i] = new string(argv[i + 1]);
}
```

`

and work with `argv_strings` instead `argv`
Do not forget `delete` pointer after.